# the syntax and the semantics of the word 'flat' in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, semantics, semantic-roles

> If they get a chance to lay their eggs, we are going to have everything eaten flat with hoppers later on.

Context: People are trying to stop locusts to land on their farms. So they suppose that they are going to have everything eaten by them if these locusts get a chance to settle there. What the word 'flat' suggests here? what is the word class of the word 'flat' here? And what particular function does it play in this context?

Comment: *Flat* here means that all of the plants will have been totally consumed, leaving only the (flat) ground behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Flat" is an adjective (flat-flatter-flattest).  It is functioning as a complement.  Compare an active sentence "The locusts ate the crops flat". It means that the locusts ate until the crops were flat to the ground, i.e. there was nothing left above ground. "Flat" is an object complement, it describes the crops.  If you rephrase that in the passive voice you get  "The crops were eaten flat (by the locusts)."  That is essentially the same structure that you have.